# android:windowActionBarOverlay & android:actionBarStyle requires api level 11

Tags: android

I am making an android app and using android-support-v7-appcompat to make sure my app support action bars from android version 2.2 and up.

I need to make the Action Bar overlay and use a translucent background so I have modified the styles.xml to this code :

```
    <resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- TRANSLUCENT THEME -->
    <style name="TranslucentAB" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BlackBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/BlackBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- TRANSLLUCENT COLOR STYLE -->
    <style name="BlackBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/halfblack</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/halfblack</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and modified manifest file to adapt the new ActionBar as :

```
android:theme="@style/TranslucentAB"
```

The problem is that the following two lines of code require API level 11 and up :

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BlackBar</item>
```

but I need to support from API level 8 and up. If I remove these two lines the app runs fine on Android 2.2 with black translucent action bar. But if I run the app in Android 4.3 the app launches with a solid white action bar. halfblack is just a png file in drawable folder with 70% black color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found solution to my problem :

I have to make separate styles.xml in res/values-v11 to support the same functionality in android 3.0 and up

Answer (score 5):

To use the action bar overlay with the support library, do this:

```
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

Notice how the style name does not include the `android:` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for replying greg but that's the problem. If I do as you stated than overlay is only working in android 2.2 and not in 4.3 that's why I have to use android:windowsActionBarOverlay. I have to manually remove the lint errors caused by this and then run the app in order to support overlays in android 3.0 and up. Is there any way  to supress api errors in XML ?

Comment: Hmmm is your theme deriving from Theme.AppCompat? (It should be). And you should only use the windowActionBarOverlay without the android: prefix. You are correct the other one will cause api errors which is as designed.

Comment: Found solution to my problem :

I have to make separate styles.xml in res/values-v11 to support the same functionality in android 3.0 and up

Comment: works for me

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>